# GCP Python SDK - Enable APIs without gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I have used the documentation here https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/enable-api#gcloud to enable new APIs via the gcloud CLI tool.  I have a service account with the owner role over my project, is it possible from within the python SDK, to enable APIs without using gcloud?  Or, is it possible to call the gcloud CLI tool from the python SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by using the [discovery API client library for Service Usage API](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/libraries#python)

You can also perform an authenticated call to the [Service Usage API enable service endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/enable)

*Let me know if you have issues and you want code example.*

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation:

[Enabling APIs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started#enabling_apis)

> You can enable Cloud APIs for a project using the console
>
> You can also enable and disable Cloud APIs using Cloud SDK and **Service Usage API**

Therefore I would recommend to [make a HTTP request](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/enable#request-body) using python to this url :`POST https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/{name=*/*/services/*}:enable`

This is the `curl` command I used to enable `analytics.googleapis.com` API

```
OAUTH_TOKEN=`gcloud auth print-access-token`

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $OAUTH_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/your-project/services/analytics.googleapis.com:enable


Response body
.......
"state": "ENABLED",
      "parent": "projects/xxxxxxx"
```

.